# Regex to match acronyms and its definitions

Tags: regex, pcre

I need a regexp to find acronyms and their definitions.
I try to match sequence of capital English letters followed by words that begin with these letters. For example:

EU European Union

I need to match against following "grammar":

```
<Capital letters> <Tabs or spaces>
<Optional "(">
<Optional tabs or spaces> <Matching definition words> <Optional tabs or spaces>
<Optional ")">
```

Following command finds all acronyms (not shorter than 2 letters) among all files in the current directory:

```
grep -aRoP '([A-Z])([A-Z])([A-Z])?([A-Z])?([A-Z])?([A-Z])?[ \t]+\(?[ \t]*\1[a-z]* \2[a-z]*(?(3) \3[a-z]*)(?(4) \4[a-z]*)(?(5) \5[a-z]*)(?(6) \6[a-z]*)[ \t]*\)?' .
```

But it has a limitation on length of acronyms (up to 6 characters).
Is it possible to rewrite the regex in more compact way removing the limitation on acronym's length? Probably this could be done with recursive patterns.

Comment: Isn't possible to use `[A-Z]{1,6}` for 1 to 6 uppercase? Or `[A-Z]+` for 1 or unlimited uppercase?

Comment: No. I need to grab acronyms that is followed by its definitions. I don't need acronyms itself (without their meaning).I need a regexp to find acronyms and their definitions. The regex must match "EU European Union" and not "EU" nor "EU Blah-Blah".

Comment: I wouldn't use regexes for this, just use a loop to check every capital letter and then check them against each of the words (which you can easily get as the matches to `[A-Z]\w+` of the rest of the string) use the right tool for the job. regexes are great but not for everything.

Comment: My regex works well. But I'm curious, can it be improved in recursive or balancing groups manner.

Answer (score 0):

```
$regex = '/(([A-Z])((?2)+))\s+\(?(((?:\s+)?(?3)\w+)(?:\s+)?(?4)?)\)?/';
$acronyms = array('EU European  Union', 'HTTP Hyper Text Transfer Protocol', 'NOT AN ACRONYM');

foreach ($acronyms as $subject) {
    $result = preg_match($regex, $subject, $matches);
    if ($result && $matches[0] === $subject) {
      echo "pass\n";
    } else {
      echo "fail\n";
    }
}
```

This should do what you're looking for.